# Adding custom field to a Bill of materials Sublist on item record in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, customization

I wanted to add a custom field on the bill of materials sublist on the item record under the manufacturing tab, I have verified other sublist fields but that would add a field on the bill of materials revision component record.
Anyone please suggest is there any other way to add a custom field to that sublist in netsuite?
[image]